# How to prevent sending ajax calls twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have many popups at map where there is a destroy action needs to be done. I attached event handlers to send ajax calls to destroy action. but it sends two ajax calls at single click, below is my code

```
   $(document).on 'click', '#map .leaflet-popup-content #delete', ->
     if confirm('Are you sure?')
       $.ajax
        type: 'POST'
        url: 'incidents/' + incident_id
        dataType: 'script'
        data:
          _method: 'delete'
          id: incident_id
        success: ->
          successFunction
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling the on click twice somehow? try printing something in the  on click to see if its being called twice.

Comment: alert triggerred once for a click

Comment: are you sure the .js is not being included twice? Usually when this happens to me i'm calling it twice some how.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide the controller action that the ajax call is being pointed to, to your **question**

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the `event` as input in your function and then call on `event` the [`.preventDefault()` method](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$(document).on('click', function(event, '#map .leaflet-popup-content #delete'){
     event.preventDeafault();
     // your code
});
```

I don't really know how to write it in coffeescript, maybe like this?

```
 $(document).on 'click', '#map .leaflet-popup-content #delete', (event) ->
     event.preventDefault()
     if confirm('Are you sure?')
       $.ajax
        type: 'POST'
        url: 'incidents/' + incident_id
        dataType: 'script'
        data:
          _method: 'delete'
          id: incident_id
        success: ->
          successFunction
```

Comment: The prevent default() is to prevent the link from its default behavior right. `<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='delete'>Delete</a>` this is the link. It's not sending request. Do we need to add prevent default?